# Does changing Profile in ChangeSet affect the Test Classes?

Tags: community, production

I have a question, and I am not able to find a satisfactory answer anywhere on the net.

Does changing the user profile in Changeset affect the Test Classes in Production Environment?

Please let me know.

Comment: How can you change user profile in changeset... Changeset for deploying codes ?

Comment: Yes... I am sorry I was not clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

When you add profile in a changeset, it basically add the profile settings for the components(metadata) that is added to changeset.
Let us take an example:
1) There is a custom field cs__c.
2) We have given read/write access on this field to a particular profile

Now when you deploy this field to target organization this field will be hidden to all profiles.
So, to overcome this move permissions based on profiles we should add profiles in changeset.